# Winter Bash is unavailable

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2013

I can't see any hats nor the Winter Bash symbol in the topbar or my profile anymore.

When I open [winterbash2013.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), I get:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

I am in Argentina if it matters.

Comment: Works for me, so...

Comment: I repro from western europe...

Comment: Me too have the same issue, oh my hats ;( (from India)

Comment: Just an example where a part of the world is discriminated

Comment: Works fine from Israel. If you go to http://stackexchange.com/ do you see the site? Might be problem with the top level domain. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see all sites just fine. I even get life updates without any problems. Everthings works so great I first thought if Winterbash is just over on the 2nd of January.

Comment: These are the last three hops on my traceroute to winterbash2013.stackexchange.com   `border1.po1-20g-bbnet1.nym008.pnap.net [216.52.95.1] / stackexchange-1.border1.nym008.pnap.net [74.201.252.22] / stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.26]`

Comment: It went down gradually for me. First, the hat page was not available (it said the usual yada about "this is totally our fault and we are already looking into it"). The charts were still there. Then some time later the rest went down as well. Approximately half an hour ago.

Comment: I reproduced this from Australia

Comment: Looks like one of the servers on the farm doesn't like hats. If fails for me, but not others in the team. We are looking.

Comment: @Oded so it's not related to location?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - shouldn't be. Just luck of what server you got stuck with...

Comment: My hat just came back (western Europe also).

Comment: @Oded: Just started working again this second.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the servers on the farm decided it doesn't like hats anymore.

It had a stern talking to and once it was understood that its future with Stack Exchange was on the line it revised its behavior.

HATS!

Comment: Anyway, its just for two more days :'(

Comment: You should really get a secret hat for fixing this. ;)